# Objective c UIFont systemFontOfSize does not work

Tags: objective-c, uifont

I am trying to change text font size with using NSAttributedString. But it's size doesn't change.

```
NSDictionary *attrDict = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor orangeColor]};

NSAttributedString *newAttString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:mytext attributes:attrDict];

[result appendAttributedString:newAttString];
```

Only text color changes. Size of result string is not 22 and also it is not bold.

Comment: If your log the value of `newAttString` does it seems correct? The one of `result` after appending `newString` too? Your issue could be afterwards.

Comment: string is correct. There is no error. But font size doesn't change.

Comment: What do you do with `result` afterwards? Do you apply again a `NSFontAttributeName` somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what `result` means at the end of your code. Are you sure you want to "append" it?

Besides, I use this code for setting fonts

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:22.0f]
```

This can be used to set different fonts and sizes respectively.

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying the attributes with the alloc, init, try doing it after with something like (with a **mutable** NSAttributedString):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *newAtt = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:mytext]; // Allocate a new NSMutableAttributedString with `mytext`
[newAtt addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20],
                                       NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor orangeColor]}
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [result length])]; // add new attributes for the length of the string `mytext`

[result setAttributedText:newAtt];
```

This answer would vary depending on what `result` is, I tested it on a `UITextView` and it worked fine, there is also an `attributedText`
property on `UILabels`.
Hope this helps.